# Problems in git push without having to clone a repository

Tags: git, github

Let's suppose that I have a project done in `HTML`, in which I have already done some versioning with it.

Assuming that I wanted to upload it on the GitHub platform, the first thing I should do is create a **repository**. And then, **clone this repository** into my computer, **throw my project files into that folder** and finally **perform git push**.

This process, which I have already carried out and I know it works.

But supposing that I did not want to clone the repository and do all the steps previously mentioned, but rather, keep the folder of my current project and push from there.

For this, I believe that I need to use the following commands:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<mygitnameuser>/<nameofrepository>.git
git push -u origin master
```

But unfortunately, I end up getting the following error message:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

I checked the username and email that are stored in `git config --global`, and they are the same as my github account, what to do?

Do I always need to make a clone, pass the files and perform git push over there?

Comment: The username and email in your Git configuration has nothing to do with Github authentication. The problem is that the ssh key with which you are authenticating does not appear to match the public key you have configured in your Github account. If things work when you clone the repository first, are you cloning using the ssh URL, or are you cloning using the http URL?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at your ssh keys on GitHub. They are located at `https://github.com/<username>.keys`. Compare that to your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (this is for Linux and Mac. Not sure where it is on Windows/`git-bash`) that you have locally.

If that is empty/unavailable then populate it via your Account settings. See how here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

You can check the SSH authentication by following these instructions: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection

Answer (score 1):

For the key error, follow docs for more https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-ssh

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent( only if you haven't created previously otherwise just skip this step)

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

copy the .pub file and paste it under `GitHub account settings -> ssh and gpg keys -> add new ssh key -> add a meaningful title like "Home laptop"`

then resume with your operations as you would do for any repository. [This article talks about a similar problem and the workflow where we don't need to clone the repository.](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/hello-world-with-git/)

Once this is done, instead of cloning the repository just create a repo in github, and in local add the origin of remote and push your changes

Comment: Unless you already have a key and agent set up, in which case just add the existing public key to your GitHub account without making a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the other repository you already cloned successfully:

```
cd /path/to/other/repo
git remote -v
```

If the remote URL starts with `https://`, then you can use a simalr URL for your new repository:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<mygitnameuser>/<nameofrepository>.git
```

That way, you will need to enter your GitHub username and password instead of dealing with SSH key setup.

Comment: Actually GitHub is moving away from username/password authentication, so it's best to stick with SSH keys as a long-term solution.