# How to solve git@github.com: Permission denied (Public key) problem?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, ssh-keys, github-token

I was working with git to commit my files and folder to new repository. Everyone time when I was pushing my code it asked for username and password (which is github token for me). To avoid this I read solution on [Configuring user and password with Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840551/configuring-user-and-password-with-git-bash) given by @manojlds.

So I ran this command:
`git remote set-url origin git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git` after reading it.

Now when I am pushing my code it **neither the problem is solved nor it is giving me option to enter username and password(token)**

After doing `$ git push` it is showing this

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read
> from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

What should I do to revert it back and so that at least I can enter username and password(token) and upload my files and folder.

Comment: Sounds like you need to generate a new SSH key

Comment: Have you generated a SSH key? Have you uploaded the public key to GitHub?

Comment: follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773184/13126651

Comment: @choroba No, I haven't generated ssh-key as I don't know how to do it. I just tried using what was there in the solution that I have mentioned.

Comment: It's outdated. GitHub doesn't support name+password authentication anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Comment: And fix your remote: `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From August 13, 2021, no longer accepts Password-based authentication. Github provides a more secure alternative to it and ie. PATs(Personal Access Tokens).

[How to generate personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

If you have done this properly, You can also refer this

[GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)